# VW units not vertically centering on responsive page

Tags: css, responsive-design

I created a responsive page and I'm using vw units to scale the fonts with the thumb rollovers title overlays.

http://toddheymandirector.com/reel/indextest.html

The first thumbnail (nike) is a font layover. the others are .png for testing purposes. I can get the .png to rollover to a vertical center but not the font. Seems like it would be simple

```
.thumb-title-container
{
height:10vw;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: -25vw;
left: 0px;
} overlays
```

Comment: Using viewport-width (vw) to set the height of something seems like bad practice.

Comment: why is it bad practice slime?

Answer (score 0):

I use the `transform` property when I'm trying to vertical center something because it's more consistent and easier to use in responsive pages. Here's what it would look like:

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="centered-child">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:rgba(110,110,110,0.85)
}
#centered-child {
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  top:50%;
  translateY(-50%);  /* There are also browser-specific calls for the translate property */
  background-color:rgba(225,225,225,0.75);
}
```

The child `div` can hold whatever you want, so you can still use a png overlay if that's what you'd rather do. Relative positioning also keeps the child `div` centered as the main wrapper shrinks with the browser size. Use media queries to make sure everything stays nice on smaller screens.

Here's a **[demo pen](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/RNRBzw)** you can test out.

Comment: thanks brian - i initially used a .png overlay for that very reason but i discovered vw units scale the fonts and using web fonts look crisper than pngs and render better on sharper displays - but this overlay animates on and off - and that worked fine for the png but the adjusting the properties seem more limited with the font approach..  did you try the link?

Comment: I did, and it looks good. I'd say go with a `div` like I mention above and use `font-size` to scale your fonts and it'll stay nice and clean.

Comment: got it to center  http://toddheymandirector.com/reel/  but the centering shifts when the browser window scales (stretch your browser window up or down - the centering shifts) i tried using percentages, vw etc..

Comment: any ideas on how to scale a centered div and stay centered as in my example  http://toddheymandirector.com/reel anyone?

Comment: Sorry, was travelling. I'll take a look at it later today.

Comment: anyone know how to keep these overlay titles vertically centered even when the browser window is scaled up or down? please see link http://toddheymandirector.com/reel

Comment: @REELHERO I've gone through the site again as carefully as I can, and the only thing I can come up with is the animation plugin you're using is calculating a height based on static divs, not on a responsive page. I haven't had the time to narrow in on which part of the script (my guess is the `containerHeight` variable - it's calculated on the page load, but doesn't recalculate on a page resize). Is there a plugin forum you can post to?